# Data strings not Comparing

Tags: c#

I am trying to compare date string in c# with the one in the Access DB 2010. Somehow my query isnt going through and I am not sure where i am going wrong. The code is as follows:

```
string dateNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

string dbcommand = "SELECT log.logID, log.datetime, log.startfloor, log.destination, log.status FROM log WHERE (((log.datetime) Like '" + dateNow + "'));";
```

In the database the records are as follows:

```
1  25/11/2013 10:18:11
2  25/11/2013 12:15:22
3  09/12/2013 09:12:46
```

Comment: I'm just going to assume you're actually sending this to a database somehow? Care to share that part?

Comment: What is data type of **log.datetime**?

Comment: Use placeholders. This will take care of data conversions as appropriate (and `datetime` *should* be an appropriate DATETIME/DATETIMEOFFSET type). Also, I really suspect the usage of `LIKE` is wrong (for *both* the improper use of a datatype and no use of `%`) - instead consider comparing dates with the appropriate range and/or precision query. If the code *starts* with dates (including the use of placeholders), as opposed to strings, then the previous task is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string dateNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

string dbcommand = "SELECT log.logID, log.datetime, log.startfloor, log.destination, log.status FROM log WHERE format(log.datetime,'dd/MM/yyyy') = '" + dateNow + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string dateNow=DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

As your row in database contains above format, you would need to compare h,m and s also

Answer (score 0):

then make it like

```
where log.datetime between '2013/11/25 00:00:00' and '2013/11/25 23:59:59'
```

or

```
string dateNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
string dbcommand = ".... where log.datetime between dateNow + ' 00:00:00' and dateNow  + ' 23:59:59'
```

and see for yourself